# Putting input field text into variable and using that for jquery JSON get request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hey so I am pretty much a jquery/javascript noob and im trying to create a simple search box where it returns movie data from the `OMDB API`. Sadly I don't think its passing the input data along correctly so I feel I am doing something wrong when passing the input text into a variable because its not passing along anything I put into my form field. Does anyone know where I am going wrong here?

Here is my code so far:

```js
    function getSearchResult() {
      var search = document.getElementById("title").innerHTML;
      jQuery.getJSON("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" + search + "=json", function(result) {
        jQuery.each(result, function(i, field) {
          jQuery("div").append(field + " ");
        });
      });
    };
```

```html
<form id="searchForm">
  Search for movie:
  <input type="text" name=movie_title id="title">
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="getSearchResult()">
</form>
```

Comment: Use Javascript console, like Firebug to start understanding what's wrong with your code, and what's happening with ajax calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a few mistakes in your code :

to get the value of an input use :

```
var search = document.getElementById("title").value;
```

instead of innerHTML

Then, the url you use to call the API is wrong, check the documentation before using : http://www.omdbapi.com/

use this url :

```
"http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" + search + "&y=&plot=short&r=json"
```

Complete Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {

    $('#search').on('click', function() {
        var search = document.getElementById("title").value;
        $.getJSON(
            "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" + search + "&y=&plot=short&r=json",
            function(result) {
                $.each(result, function(i, field){
                    $("body").append(field + " ");
                });
            }
        );
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
    Search for movie:<input type="text" name="movie_title" id="title" />
    <input type="button" id="search" value="Submit" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a bit of an odd hybrid of vanilla JS and jQuery going on there; consider changing your approach to fully utilize the tools that jQuery puts at your disposal.  Please find code below that might help point you in that direction (note the updates to the HTML and the attachment of onClick to the button itself):

JS:

```
$('#searchForm input[type="button"]').on('click', function(){
    var search = $('#searchForm input').text();
    var searchResult = $('#searchResult'); //save reference to DOM object
    $.getJSON("https://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" + search + "=json", function(response){
        console.log(response);
        searchResult.empty();
        if(response.Response === 'False') {
            searchResult.append('<p>'+response.Error+'</p>');
        } else {
            $.each(result, function(i, field){
                searchResult.append('<p>'+field+'</p>');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="searchForm">
  Search for movie:<input type="text" name=movie_title id="title">
  <input type="button" value="Submit" >
</form>
<div id="searchResult"></div>
```

You can run it here (although none of my quick searches returned a result, so I can't verify the success condition):
https://jsfiddle.net/wct58tco/